# what parameter affect the training time in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am doing a project where I need to change the parameter or something in cifar10 by CNN, and then collect the different training time of them. Does anyone know which parameters should I change? 
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it explained in the class notes or something?

Comment: Voted to close: Too-broad. This question does not allow anyone to answer it except  by guessing. Missing is reference to which model is used to train on CIFAR 10.